# How can one determine if an svn working copy is from branch or trunk?

Tags: svn, branch, svn-trunk

My project has the standard trunk/tags/branches structure and typically work in the trunk.  Before the holiday, I switched to the Branch to make an isolated change and now I have lost recall if I ever switched back to trunk.  Is there a way to check if my local-working copy corresponds to the branch or trunk?

I want to start making more changes for the upcoming release and when I commit at the end-of-day, I don't want to commit to the branch and I am not ready to merge the branch.

Comment: Though perhaps not an exact duplicate, I refer you to my answer for [How to list switched svn directories recursively in a working copy?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12773072/115690) for a command-line technique and to [How can I see which branch is current?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6100733/115690) for a graphical technique to answer a more general form of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got the answer for command-line tools, but if you're using TortoiseSVN on Windows, you can just right-click your working copy and click "Properties". There is a Subversion tab in that dialog which tells you the URL your working copy is pointing to.

Comment: This answer prompted me to check the other perspectives in my IDE and I found the properties that showed me what I needed to know.  But that was after I did a round-about poke.  I found an innocuous file and committed it -- then I went to the SVN browser (website tool) and looked to see if the trunk or branch logged the event.  I got away with this since I am also the Admin for the repo.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the svn command line utility `svn info` from the working copy root directory. It will tell you revision, repository url and much more.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, the IDE and command line are using different SVN clients.  If I use the command line, it will force an update before I can even get the info.  The update is not compatible with the IDE (trust me I have no choice) and essentially corrupts my project with respect to the IDE.  But in the spirit of this answer, I tried to dump the svn hidden files to see if I could locate the meta-data --- no luck.

Answer (score 2):

For WC-root, you have to use `svn info` command and in it's output check content any of two values of keys: `URL` or `Relative URL`

Sample from my WC

```
>svn info
...
URL: https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/proofsheets.natasha/branches/FullHTML
Relative URL: ^/branches/FullHTML
...
```

Comment: I have an IDE compatibility issue with the SVN client and the command line (see my comment to @Anders Forsgren above).  Good answer, but did not help me on this project.

Comment: @mobibob - create copy of used WC, upgrade it (copy) and use `svn info`. Remove copy after all